# How do I pass the current value of 'p' using the ${{ each p in parameters.param }} to a bash script in an Azure pipeline?

Tags: bash, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a pipeline template that I am calling to loop through a list of parameter values that I need to split and assign to two variables for my task -- because I can't use multi-dimensional arrays in Azure pipelines :(

The question is: How do I get the current value a loop is presenting into bash to perform an action with it?

Example:

```
parameters:
- name: NameAndID
  type: object
  default: []
- name: jobsToRun
  type: string
  default: ''


jobs:
- job: DoTheThing
  displayName: "Update with val A and val B"
  steps:
    - ${{ each p in parameters.NameAndID }}:
      ??  << assign Bash accessible variable 'NAME_ID' to ${{ p }} >> ??
      - bash: 
          AF=$NAME_ID | cut -d '~' -f1)
          echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=AF_NAME]$AF"
          PROJ=$NAME_ID | cut -d '~' -f2)
          echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=PROJ_NUM]$PROJ"
```

So assuming the parameter values passed are:

```
A~1
B~2
C~3
...
```

For each instance the script should create the variables

```
Loop 1
  $AF_NAME = A
  $PROJ_NUM = 1
Loop 2
  $AF_NAME = B
  $PROJ_NUM = 2
Loop 3
  $AF_NAME = C
  $PROJ_NUM = 3
```

and so on...
So the step I can't figure out is
<< assign bash accessible variable to ${{ p }} >>
How can I assign the new value of ${{ p }} to a variable that bash can read each time the loop occurs?

Also, I'm pretty green on this so be specific please. :)

TIA

Freymish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I get the current value a loop is presenting into bash to perform an action with it?

You can use the following script in bash:

```
NAME_ID=${{ p }}
```

Then the variable `NAME_ID` will have the value of the parameter in the current loop.

Here is my test script:

```
trigger: none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

parameters:
- name: NameAndID
  type: object
  default:
  - A~1
  - B~2
  - C~3


jobs:
- job: DoTheThing
  displayName: "Update with val A and val B"
  steps:
    - ${{ each p in parameters.NameAndID }}:
      - bash: |
          NAME_ID=${{ p }}
          AF=$( echo "$NAME_ID" | cut '-d~' "-f1" )
          PROJ=$( echo "$NAME_ID" | cut '-d~' "-f2" )

          echo "$NAME_ID"
          echo "$AF"
          echo "$PROJ"
```

And it works perfectly:

[image]    [image]    [image]

Comment: That worked! Thanks so much. One follow-up, why the single and double quotes on the 
 `cut '-d~' "-f1" `
part?

Comment: @Freymish These are not necessary and you can use your cut commands instead! :) I'm not familiar with bash and directly use the commands in a tutorial.